# E^2={x^2:x∈E}.Prove that E^2 is measurable whenever E is a measurable subset of R.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lipschitz-functions, measurable-functions

I have already proven that if Φ(x) is a strictly increasing Lipschitz function then Φ(E) is measurable whenever E is a measurable subset of R. And then by use it I proved that $\sqrt{E}$ is measurable whenever E is a measurable   subset of R. So maybe I should construct a Lipschitz function based on $x^{2}$, but how ? And how about $E^{3}$

Comment: $E^2$ usually represents $\{(x,y):x,y\in E\}$ just by the way

Comment: Note x^2 is lipshitz on any bounded set

Comment: Use $E_n = E \cap [0,n]$ which is bounded, with your result.